# Phonegap alert doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am using Codorva 2.5. I use this way to show an alert view:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
            message,
            callback,
            'Warning', //title
            options
            );
```

It works fine on iOS but does not on Android. I don't want to use alert() function of javascript. Do I make any mistake?

Here is config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
    <content src="www/page/main/main.html" />

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>

</plugins>
</cordova>
```

My Android application structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slide Mistake.You don't have write anything.Write in this way.

```
navigator.notification.confirm('Hello World',onConfirm,'Confirm','No,Yes');

function onConfirm(buttonIndex)
{
}
```

and add this sentence in your `config.xml` file.

```
<gap:plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
```

Ok.Now i have got your mistake.The code you have shown is for `plugin.xml` file.This is not the code for `config.xml` file.All plugins that you have declared that are useful for blackberry devices.So it will definetly not going to open in android.

There must be a `config.xml` and `plugin.xml` file in your project's root directory.
so save this code as a `plugin.xml` file -> create one file as `config.xml` file and write below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id = "xyz"
    versionCode="1"
        version = "1.0.0">

<gap:plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>

</widget>
```

Sure,This will gone a work.

Comment: @Nguyen Minh Binh-If you are using simple Alert then simply use navigator.notification.alert('hi',null,'Warning','Ok');

Comment: Nguyen Minh Binh-Have you write the way i have written? just for testing write the code that i have putted in the answer and add that sentence i have told you to add in the config.xml file.It should be working.Right now i have tested it on Android

Comment: When I initialize the project with PhoneGap's create script, I saw that it has the plugin declaration. but, without the word: `gap`. I also tried to put this word. Building fail.

Comment: edit your question with your config.xml file.show us your config.xml file code.So one can help you.There seems to be a problem in your config.xml file.

Comment: Yeah.i have updated my answer.You can see my answer.This is the code for plugin.xml file not for the config.xml file.There must be a config.xml file.The code you have putted is useful for iOS.but there must require one widget tag in your config.xml file.

Comment: Sorry but, the PhoneGap Android project doesn't have any `plugin.xml` file. Everything are declared at `res/xml/config.xml` file. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android. I also tried to create `plugin.xml` file at root directory, nothing change.

Comment: Ok.If you want to write in the config.xml file then you can write it.But the way you have written the config.xml file is not correct.Check this. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml This is the correct format.

Comment: That config file is used when you want to build your app with Adobe PhoneGap Build. I am using android SDK/eclipse to build my Android app, and Xcode to build iOS app. https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: Yeah.I know you are using eclipse and Xcode.I am developing both way.Using Pb and Eclipse.I am including same config.xml file and its working correctly in my application.May be you have setup your project wrongly.On PhoneGap site the setup of eclipse project is not good.Refer this link.This is perfect tutorial. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html                                                                     May be you forgot to write permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I accept your answer because I know what you give is correct. But, in my case, I face this issue because I use a unique `www` folder across platforms (ios/android). The root cause is that PhoneGap requests 2 difference versions of Cordova-2.5.0.js. I replaced the file generated by `phonegap/lib/android/bin/create` script and it works fine. For iOS target, I have to generate another one by `phonegap/lib/iOS/bin/create` script. Unbelivable!

Comment: oooh...really Unbelievable!!